# Request Ajax failed getting http status 403

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, ajaxform

I am trying to save some store details and getting a response from the controller using Ajax but when I am trying to do so the request is not received by the Controller please see the code and help me what I am doing wrong here.

**MasterAjaxClass:** The class is used to send the request and receive a response

```
class MasterAjax{
    constructor(){
        this.requestType = null;
        this.url = null;
        this.timeout = 100000;
        this.enctype =  null;
        this.data = null;
        this.processData = null;
        this.contentType = null;
        this.responseData = null;
        this.responseStatus = null;
        this.responseStatusCode = null;
    }
    
    requestData(callBack){
        
        var parameterError=false;
        if(null == this.requestType){
            parameterError=true;
            console.log("Error: Request Type can't be null");
        }    
        if(null === this.url || undefined === this.url || "undefined" === this.url){
            parameterError=true;
            console.log("Error: URL can't be null");
        }  
        if(null == this.data || this.data.length <= 0){
            //console.log("Warning: Data is null");
        }
        if(parameterError === false){
            /*toggleSpinnerOn();  */
            $.ajax({
                type : this.requestType,
                enctype : this.enctype,
                processData : this.processData, 
                contentType : this.contentType, 
//              url : global_contextPath+"/"+this.url,
            url : global_contextPath+"/"+this.url,
                data: this.data,
                timeout : this.timeout,
                success : function(responseData,textStatus) {
                    /*toggleSpinnerOff();*/
                    callBack(responseData,textStatus);
                },
                error : function(responseData,textStatus) {
                    /*toggleSpinnerOff();  */
                    callBack(responseData,textStatus); 
                }
            }); 
        }
        //return this.responseData;
    }
}
```

**Ajax Request method**

```
function saveStore(){
 
let formData = new FormData();

//formData.append("key" , Value ) ; 
    formData.append("storeName", $("#storeName").val());
    formData.append("country", $("#country").val());
    formData.append("city", $("#city").val());
    formData.append("street", $("#street").val());
    formData.append("address", $("#address").val());
    formData.append("zipCode", $("#zipCode").val());
    formData.append("storeDescription", $("#storeDescription").val());
    formData.append("storeOpenTime", $("#storeOpenTime").val());
    formData.append("logoURL", $("#file-input-2").val());


    console.log($("#storeName").val());
    console.log($("#country").val());
    console.log($("#city").val());
    console.log($("#street").val());
    console.log($("#address").val());
    console.log($("#zipCode").val());
    console.log($("#storeDescription").val());
    console.log($("#storeOpenTime").val());
    console.log($("#file-input-2").val());

    var obj = new MasterAjax();
    obj.requestType = "POST";
    obj.url = "store/saveStore";
    obj.data = formData;
    obj.enctype ="multipart/form-data";   
    obj.contentType = false;

    console.log("---------------------------")

    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0]+ ': ' + pair[1]); 
    }
    console.log("---------------------------")

    obj.requestData(function(responseData){
        console.log(responseData);
        if(responseData.status == "OK" || responseData.status == "ok"){
            alert("success");
            console.log(responseData)
        }else{
            alert(" failed");
            console.log(responseData)
        }
    }); 
}
```

**StoreForm.jsp**

```
<form:form name="storeForms" modelAttribute="storeForm"
            method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <%--                <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        <h5 class="alert-heading">Failed to Save</h5>
                        <hr>
                        <p>${error}</p>
                    </div>
                </c:if>
 --%>
            <!-- Hidden For Update employee  -->
            <form:input type="hidden" path="id" />
            <!-- First row -->
            <div class="form-row row-eq-spacing-sm">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <label for="first-name" class="required">Store Name</label>
                    <form:input type="text" path="storeName" class="form-control"
                        id="storeName" placeholder="Store Name" required="required" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <label for="last-name" class="required">Country</label>
                    <form:input type="text" id="country" path="country" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Second row container -->
            <div class="form-row row-eq-spacing-sm">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <label for="first-name" class="required">City</label>
                    <form:input type="text" id="city" path="city" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <label for="last-name" class="required">Street</label>
                    <form:input type="text" id="street" path="street" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Third row container -->
            <div class="form-row row-eq-spacing-sm">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <label for="first-name" class="required">Address</label>
                    <form:input type="text" id="address" path="address" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <label for="last-name" class="required">Zip Code</label>
                    <form:input type="text" id="zipCode" path="zipCode" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-row row-eq-spacing-sm">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <label for="first-name" class="required">Store Description</label>
                    <form:input type="text" path="storeDescription" id="storeDescription"
                        class="form-control" />

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <label for="last-name" class="required">Store Timings</label>
                    <form:input type="text" path="storeOpenTime" id="storeOpenTime" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="custom-file">
                <form:input type="file" path="logoURL" id="file-input-2"
                    data-default-value="Size of logo should not Exeed 1mb" />
                <label for="file-input-2">Choose logo</label>
            </div>

            <!-- Submit button container -->
            <div class="text-right">
                <!-- text-right = text-align: right -->
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="saveStore();" value="Add Store">
            </div>
        </form:form>
```

**Controller Method**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/store")
public class StoreController {


    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveStore" , method = {RequestMethod.POST},consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
    public APIResponseModal saveStore(@ModelAttribute("storeForm") StoresDTO store,@RequestPart("logoURL") MultipartFile file) {
        logger.info("Store Save MEthod callled !!!!!!!!");
        Stores storeModal  = new Stores();
        String logopath = "";
        APIResponseModal apiResponse = new Utils().getDefaultApiResponse();
        List<String> errorList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            if(store !=null){
                storeModal = new Stores(store);
                if(!file.isEmpty()) {
                    if(file.getSize()>1000000) {//1000000 bytes == 1 mb
                        errorList.add("File size should be less than 1 MB");
                    }
                    logopath = Utils.storeLogoPath(file);
                }
                storeService.saveStore(storeModal, errorList,logopath);
                if(errorList.isEmpty() && !Utils.isNotNull(errorList)) {
                    apiResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK);
                    apiResponse.setData("--");
                    apiResponse.setMessage("Store Saved Successfully !!");
                }else {
                    apiResponse.setMessage("Failed to save store !!");
                    apiResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                }
            }           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            apiResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            apiResponse.setData("--");
            apiResponse.setMessage("Error Occured at our end !!");          
        }
        logger.info("API RESPONSE:: ::"+ apiResponse);
        return apiResponse;
    }
}
```

**Error On browser Console**

```
Status :403
```

Comment: 403 is usually Forbidden stuff

Comment: You need to share the security configurations

Comment: @PatelRomil I do not have any security configurations done by myself yet I just started this project Please see the project  [here](https://github.com/Shivam5197/eCom) I just added a dependency for   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>